# Dragging a sprite right and left?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Im wondering how to do this. How can i make it so that when a user taps and HOLDS my sprite they can drag it across the x axis only, maintaining the same y value?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d

When it sets the position of the sprite instead of setting the y position to that of the touch, just set it to a fixed value where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you handle your touches:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.rect, touchLocation)){
     sprite.position = ccp(touchLocation.x,sprite.position.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *Drag = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint CurrentPosition = [Drag locationInView:self.view];
    CurrentPosition.x = Sprite.center.x;
    Sprite.center = CurrentPosition;
}
```

I created a slider like this: https://github.com/Antem/Custom-Slider-xCode